# Failure to Open SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to write a database for a small business to handle reservations, It's written using the 21 API for Lollipop, I've included the DBAdapter and the create reservation classes below. When I try to hit Submit, I get this error (StackOverflow won't let me post the entire error, but here's some of it --> 
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()' on a null object reference
            at net.stein13.reserveit.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:53)
            at net.stein13.reserveit.NewReservation.submitReservation(NewReservation.java:29)`

Was trying to figure it out with my AP Computer Science teacher, but she didn't know enough about Android to help me figure it out..

New Reservation class - http://pastebin.com/ALn9Q2sg
DBAdapter class - http://pastebin.com/07PZSiT1

Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the pastebins are the same code that you are compiling and running? The line numbers from your error messages don't match at all.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I took the code directly from the last time I compiled it- and the error came from when I ran it on an AVD and clicked Submit

Comment: Note that the error message tells you that the NPE occurs at line 53 of `DBAdapter.java`. (If you click on this line in your IDE, it will jump straight to the line of code with the problem.) However, in the pastebin, this line is blank. It appears that you inserted a blank line somewhere between the time you compiled and ran the app and the time you created the pastebin. Please be careful of this in the future as it can cause a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you never initialize the `DBHelper` member variable. However, since `DBAdapter` extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, there is no need for `DBHelper` at all. This is because every `DBAdapter` is an `SQLiteOpenHelper`. This means that you can call all of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` methods directly on any `DBAdapter`. For example, you should change your `open()` method to

```
db = getWritableDatabase();
```

You should also completely remove your `close()`. `SQLiteOpenHelper` already has a `close()` method which does all the work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it perfectly, now I just have to fix a few minor things, but there is indeed a database now! :)